# asp.net post javascript ajax to usercontrol

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

**Javascript:**

```
function Proposal(GetProposal, ProductName, ProductID) {

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Page.ascx/Proposal",
      data: JSON.stringify({ GetProposal: GetProposal, ProductName: ProductName, ProductID: ProductID }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",

      failure: function (response) {
          alert(response.d);
                                   }
     });

     }
```

**Page.ascx:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Proposal(string GetProposal, string ProductName, string ProductID)
{

HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("MyPage");

}
```

When i try to post ajax to Proposal method i get below error :

```
POST http://localhost:63290/Page.ascx/Proposal 403 (Forbidden)
```

Where i miss what to change in my code ?

Comment: Your Proposal Method is being hit or not?

Comment: It looks like you have user control - Page.**ascx**. I think it should be a page, with aspx extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call this method,because ascx controls don't represent a real URL that can be accessed from a client machine. They're server-side meant to embed in other pages.

instead you may try to put your method in **.aspx** page, and then call method

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "NewPage.aspx/Proposal",
      data: JSON.stringify({ GetProposal: GetProposal, ProductName: ProductName, ProductID: ProductID }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",

      failure: function (response) {
          alert(response.d);
                                   }
     });
```

and your **NewPage.aspx** must contain same method you wrote

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void Proposal(string GetProposal, string ProductName, string ProductID)
{

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("MyPage");

}
```